# Equivalent of MYSQL AUTO_INCREMENT column in table information_schema.tables in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

**MYSQL:**

I am using  AUTO_INCREMENT column in table information_schema.tables to get next id.

Like below :

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'TableName' AND table_schema = 'DBNAME' ;
```

**SQL SERVER :**

What is Equivalent of MYSQL AUTO_INCREMENT column in table information_schema.tables in sql server?

I want to achieve same functionality in sql server 2012.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found system function [IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) which does same as I want.

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')+1 as AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Hope it will help someone else too.

Thanks